# Simple exit script (if - then )

Tags: linux

I'm so new to programming it hurts!  I'm trying to make a very very basic exit out of the termial script.  Basically you run the scipt. It will then ask if you want to exit terminal or stay.  When I choose either 1 or 2, it just returns to the terminal.

Ideally, I wanted to type "logout" and I would get the same script with the same options, but I've been trying to 2 days and it doesn't make sense.

Thank you in adavance!

```
#! /bin/bash
# Created by Sarge on Feb. 9, 2015
#This script locks the screen when user logs out
# User must type "logout" and will then have to enter their password
# After the correct password for the user is enter
# the screen will go into lock mode

# clear the screen
clear

# exit options
echo "1. Exit"
echo "2. No"

# exit screen
echo "Exit terminal? (1 = Exit.  2 = No)."

# user input
read user_input

if [ $user_input = 1 ] ; then
    exit
elif [ $user_input = 2 ] ; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The script is run in a different process than the interactive shell. `exit` therefore ends just the script. Note that the shell may not be what logged the user in and terminating it won't logout the user (eg. when the user runs shell within his shell). If it is enough for you to kill the shell, you can run `kill $PPID`.

It is quite hard to find what exactly logged the user in. The best approximation would be to climb the process tree up until the parent process is no longer running under the user you want to logout, then kill the child process (or all processes in this subtree to be sure nothing survives). You can use `pstree` to visualize what you need to do and `ps` to actually do it.

Comment: StenSoft: I guess I'm asking if I could take "exit" and define that to trigger my terminal script.

Comment: @Sarge you can "alias exit=myscript", but read StenSoft's answer *carefully* - the point is that your functionality *cannot* (reasonably) be part of an external script, it must be a function. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32351/is-there-a-way-to-lock-command-line

Answer (score 0):

use `==` not `=` operator like so:

```
if [ $user_input == 1 ] ; then
    exit
elif [ $user_input == 2 ] ; then
    exit 0
fi
```

you may also choose to replace this with `-eq` like so:

```
if [ $user_input -eq 1 ] ; then
    exit
elif [ $user_input -eq 2 ] ; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Reason:

In most programming languages including BASH,

1. = is known as the assignment operator that assigns value on the right side to the variable on the left side
2. == is the equality check operator that checks for equality of LHS and RHS and returns either true or false based on comparison result
   (This is what is done in  the if condition in this program).

Comment: That makes since.  I'm still unable to close the actual terminal.  I used:  pkill -f logout.sh to end the script.  That's works perfectly.  Very helpful so far.

Comment: `==` is a bashism and won't work in a different shell or with `/bin/[`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to run off a key word.  Created a bin folder in my main directory.  I put my script in bin. Than I tried Alias = "end" = "logout".  Now when I just type "end" (no quotes), my script automatically runs!!!  Whoop!